# how to add gesture recognizer to UI Label?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

[image]

I am trying to add tap gesture to the February label like the picture above, but I don't know why when I add gesture recognizer to the UI Label, it doesn't work, but if I assign that tap gesture to the view (the blue box) , it worked as I am expected.

can we actually add gesture recognizer to UI Label? or what should I do to add gesture to the UI label?

```
class AttendanceListVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dummyView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        prepareTapGestureToChooseMonth()


    }

}



    func prepareTapGestureToChooseMonth() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AttendanceListVC.tapFunction(sender:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1


        monthLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        dummyView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func tapFunction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {


       // show pop up

    }


}
```

Comment: Use a button not a label

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> can we actually add gesture recognizer to UI Label

Certainly. But you would also need to turn on the label's `isInteractionEnabled` if you want the gesture recognizer to *do* anything.

```
monthLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
monthLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

<sub>(Be warned, however, that this may not be a good user interface. Users will not expect to be able to tap a label, and it doesn't respond in a lively visible way to being tapped. Perhaps "February" in your interface should be the title of a *button*.)</sub>